# gmDate not giving the right time

Tags: php, date, timezone

I want to send out a reminder text message at 10 am two days before the end date (`$endDate`). The 10 am is in the relevant time zone of the user. Messages are sent out by the server on a UTC/GMT time base. (The mysqlToUnix and unixToMysql methods simply convert Unix timestamp to YY-MM-DD HH:MM format and vice versa. In this example we are using Hawai'ian time.)

First subtract 2 days from the end date.
Second check if we still have time to send the message.
Then set the time to 10 am on the correct day (local time).
Finally convert to GMT/UTC.

```
date_default_timezone_set("pacific/honolulu");
$unixTemp = $thisMessageSchedule->mysqlToUnix($endDate);
$unixTwoDays = strtotime("- 2 days", $unixTemp);// works fine
$unixNow = time();
if ($unixTwoDays >= $unixNow) // if less than 2 days OR already finished
{
  $unixFinalDateTime=strtotime("10 am",$unixTwoDays);
  $mysqlFinalDateTime=$thisMessageSchedule->unixToMysql($unixFinalDateTime);

  $unixGmtDateTime=gmdate($unixFinalDateTime);
  $reminderGmtDateTime=$thisMessageSchedule->unixToMysql($unixGmtDateTime);
```

**RESULT:**

```
$mysqlFinalDateTime = correct day 10 am.
$reminderGmtDateTime = correct day 10 am.
The correct GMT result would be same day but 8 PM to send the message at 10 am local time.
```

I have used `gmdate` a couple of times before without problem. Am I missing something obvious? The functions seem v straightforward but ...

Grateful for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

*GENUINE QUESTION - should I delete this whole question and answer? (Pls post suggestion in comment below.) Now that I know the answer, this now looks like a really dumb question. BUT I spent literally hours trying to work out what was wrong. If someone else hits the same misunderstanding and sees this then it is useful. But I know SO hates dumb stuff so should I leave this Q/A or delete them?*

---

**"ANSWER"**

`gmdate()` does NOT return a timestamp as I thought. It returns a formatted date/time string.

So instead of

```
gmdate($unixFinalDateTime);
```

I needed

```
gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unixFinalDateTime);
```

Oops!